# Area under mapping

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can some one help me with this problem:

Let $f:R^2\rightarrow R^2$ be defined by $\displaystyle{f(x,y)=(e^{x+y},e^{x-y})}$

Find the area of the image of the region $\{(x,y) \in R^2 : 0<x,y<1 \}$ under the mapping f

Comment: You can compute the Jacobian of your mapping ($2e^{2x}$) and integrate that over the unit square to get $e^2-1$.

Comment: @Mark McClure....will you explain that why the region is a unit square?